# How to initialize ViewController from storyboard using it's Coder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I realize that this might be difficult to achieve, but I would like to be able to initialize `ViewControllers` from `storyboard` using `init(coder: NSCoder)` function directly. I mean not using `storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: coder: )` - I know I could use this, but this is what I would like to skip. Instead I would prefer to have a init in `ViewController` like this:
`init(viewModel: ViewModel)` and use this init to initialize this `ViewController` from the `storyboard`. Inside this init I imagine having some mechanism that would open my `storyboard`, and extracted it's coder somehow, so that I could write:

```
static let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "Game")

private let viewModel: ViewModel

init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    let identifier = String(describing: Self.self)
    let coder: NSCoder = Self.storyboard.somehowGetTheCoderForViewController(withId: identifier)
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

Problem is how to read storyboard in such a way that I was able to get the coder of particular ViewController from it.
Again - I know this can be solved by using something like this

```
storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: String(describing: Self.self)) { coder in
    Self.init(coder: coder, viewModel: viewModel)
}
```

But Im looking for a way to not use `instantiateViewController`, and just be able to get the `coder`, so that later I could just `initiate` VC like this:

```
let viewController = ViewContorller(viewModel: viewModel)
```

So the question is how to unpack `storyboard`, and retrieve `coder` object for some `ViewController`.

Comment: How about using [this other init](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init) instead?

Comment: That works with xib, not storyboards

Comment: The "discussion" section of that initialiser also says "When using a storyboard to define your view controller and its associated views, you never initialize your view controller class directly." How about just using a xib file instead? I don't think there'd be too much of a difference, functionally.

Comment: I do use xib files mostly, but Im in the process of redesigning large app to use different architecture. Moving all of this views from storyboard to xib is a lot ow work, so I was looking for a way to load them from xib directly.

Comment: Currently I have a protocol that requires Storyboard variable and provides simpler method for loading this. If I can't find a way to get to that coder object, I will just stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to do this.

As the documentation of [`init(nibName:bundle:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621359-init) says:

> This is the designated initializer for this class. When using a storyboard to define your view controller and its associated views, you never initialize your view controller class directly. Instead, view controllers are instantiated by the storyboard either automatically when a segue is triggered or programmatically when your app calls the `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method of a storyboard object.

When initialising a VC using an initialiser, *that* initialiser is what you should use, not `init(coder:)`. If you use storyboards, then you should use `instantiateViewController`, or use segues to get new VCs.

So to achieve this syntax:

```
let viewController = ViewContorller(viewModel: viewModel)
```

You can put your VCs in xib files, and do:

```
init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    let identifier = String(describing: Self.self)
    let coder: NSCoder = Self.storyboard.somehowGetTheCoderForViewController(withId: identifier)
    super.init(nibName: String(describing: Self.self), bundle: nil)
}
```

If you must use storyboards, then you can't use an initialiser syntax for initialising VCs. You can instead make a factory method, such as:

```
let viewController = ViewContorller.from(viewModel: viewModel)
```

And implement it using `UIStoryboard.instantiateViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

This is why the initializer `instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)` exists.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/3213989-instantiateviewcontroller

You receive the `coder` and use it to call a custom initializer that itself calls the `coder` initializer but also does other custom initialization.

To illustrate, suppose we have a ViewController class with a `message` String property to be presented to the user in a UILabel when the view appears. So we've given ViewController an `init(coder:message:)` initializer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var lab : UILabel!
    var message: String = ""
    convenience init(coder:NSCoder, message:String) {
        self.init(coder:coder)!
        self.message = message
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.lab.text = self.message
    }
}
```

Left to its own devices, however, the runtime will never call our `init(coder:message:)` initializer; it knows nothing of it! The only way the runtime knows to instantiate a view controller from a storyboard is by calling `init(coder:)`. But *we* can call `init(coder:message:)` when *we* instantiate the view controller from the storyboard.

Suppose this is the storyboard's initial view controller, and we're calling it in the scene delegate at launch time:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, 
    willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, 
    options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let message = "Howdy, world!" // or whatever
        self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController = sb.instantiateInitialViewController {
            return ViewController(coder: $0, message: message)
        }
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

We call `instantiateViewController(identifier:creator:)` and the `creator:` function calls `init(coder:message:)` — which, in turn, calls `init(coder:)`. Thus our use of the `creator:` function is legal, and the view appears correctly.